# Find probability of a union of two sets, given information about three

Tags: probability

Given that events $A$ and $B$ are independant and also $P(A) =2/3$, $P(B) =1/4$, $P(C) =1/4$, $P(A\cup B\cup C) = 1$. How can I find $P(B\cup C)$ = ?

Comment: Ok if the events are independent, shouldn't there be some non-zero probability that none of the events occurs?

Comment: @ghosts_in_the_code A and B are independent.  C may not be.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Making use of the independency you can find $$P(A\cup B)=P(A)+P(B)-P(A)P(B)=\frac23+\frac14-\frac23\frac14=\frac34=1-P(C)$$

Combining this with $P(A\cup B\cup C)=1$ you can conclude that $$P((A\cup B)\cap C)=0$$

so that $$P(B\cup C)=P(B)+P(C)$$

Comment: Very nice. +1  .